# Previous Month variable SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using multiple variables in a stored procedure to calculate previous day, week, month, year.

All are working fine apart from previous month which is not including the last day of the month.

So for example for October, when I query the table it is only including 1st to the 30th and missing out of the last day.

These are the variables I am using in the stored proc:

```
DECLARE @today      DATE = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()+1);

DECLARE @previous_month_from DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @today) - 1, 0)

DECLARE @previous_month_to   DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1)
```

Any ideas what needs to change for previous month range?

Comment: When I run that query I get `2023-10-01` and `2023-10-31` for the from/to variables respectively, so it "looks" to be working fine. Perhaps the problem is you are using `BETWEEN` on a date **and time** value, and therefore expecting a value like `2023-10-31T17:00:01` to be "between" `2023-10-01` and `2023-10-31`?

Comment: `DECLARE @today      DATE = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()+1);` Why the `+1`?

Comment: use EOMONTH instead of whatever you're doing

Comment: Must be to do with the timestamp, these are date time values, so the 1 row that i am missing in this example has a datetime of 2023-10-31 09:07:35.757

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this seems to work,

```
DECLARE @today      DATE = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())

DECLARE @today      DATE = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())

DECLARE @previous_month_to   DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @today) , 0)
```

and then in my WHERE Cause use

```
dt >= @previous_month_from  AND dt < @previous_month_to   THEN 1 END) AS 
previous_month
```

Thanks everyone for the suggestions!

Much appreciated!

Comment: BTW - There's an implicit conversion between DateTime and Date, so you can just do `declare @today date = GetDate()`. Also, since you're using separate `declare` statements for each variable, you can do `declare @tomorrow date = DateAdd(day, 1, @Today);`

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server has a method called [EOMONTH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) that returns the last day of the month of the date you supply it, and also takes in an optional argument for month offset - so you can simply do this:

```
DECLARE @previous_month_to   DATE = EOMONTH(GetDate(), -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate DATETIME = '2023-11-20';
DECLARE @FirstDayOfPreviousMonth DATETIME, @LastDayOfPreviousMonth DATETIME;

SET @FirstDayOfPreviousMonth = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @CurrentDate) - 1, 0);
SET @LastDayOfPreviousMonth = DATEADD(SECOND, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @FirstDayOfPreviousMonth));

SELECT 
    @FirstDayOfPreviousMonth AS 'Start of Previous Month', 
    @LastDayOfPreviousMonth AS 'End of Previous Month';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @today_ DATE = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE());
DECLARE @first_day_of_current_month_ DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, 
DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @today_), 0);
DECLARE @first_day_of_previous_month_ DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, 
@first_day_of_current_month_);
DECLARE @last_day_of_previous_month_ DATE = DATEADD(DAY, -1, 
@first_day_of_current_month_);

 SELECT @first_day_of_previous_month_ AS PreviousMonthStart, 
 @last_day_of_previous_month_ AS PreviousMonthEnd;
```

Comment: A *good* answer includes an explanation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).